# JAXB Marshaller skipping "-" (hypen) from string

Tags: java, jaxb

I/P - **PostalCode : 1001-2002**

O/P - **< PostalCode> 10012002 < /PostalCode>**

Expected - **< PostalCode>1001-2002 < /PostalCode>**

Following are the marshaller properties,

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM 'http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.025/cXML.dtd'>");
```